# This function is analytic iff and only iff

Tags: complex-analysis

This particular question was asked in my complex analysis and I was not able to solve it. SO, I am asking for help.

> Let p(z) , q(z) be two non-zero complex polynomials. Then p(z)$\bar{q(z)}$ is analytic iff

(i) p(z) is constant

(ii)p(z) q(z) is constant

(iii)q(z) is constant

(iv) $\bar{p(z)} $q(z) is constant

I think q(z) is constant should be answer as then p(z)$\bar{q(z)}$ will be analytic but answer is (iv) for which I have no explanation or which result should be used.

Can you please shed some light on how to prove it?

Thank you!!

Comment: I assume you mean to have $\overline{q(z)}$ and $\overline{p(z)}$? Neither is correct. Either condition will imply that $p(z)\overline{q(z)}$ is analytic but the "only if" fails for each one individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is (iii) as you you guessed. If $p(z)\overline {q(z)}$ is analytic then  $\overline {q(z)}$ is anayltic on the region obtained by removing the zeros of $p$. But this implies that $q$ is a  constant there. By continuity it is  a  constant on $\mathbb C$.